# Use % sign in search query?

Tags: search, twitter

How to search for percentage (%) sing through Google, Twitter Search etc.?
The search engines use it as a special character of just completely ignore it. I've tried to search for an HTML code of %, which is `&#37;`, but it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can not do what you want with Google as it works today.**
You cannot search for special characters in Google Web Search nor Gmail.
Google doesn't recognize special search characters like square brackets, parentheses, currency symbols, the ampersand, the pound sign, and asterisks.

**These are the only symbols that return any results.**

- & (ampersand)
- _ (underscore)

Check out the link below, an interesting article, it is 2005, but the same applies today, you still cannot search for special chars:

[link text](http://www.marketingshift.com/2006/3/google-special-character-search-string.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no special entity for percent char, but You could provide its decimal code **`&#37;`**